# Почему KendoUI Grid не отображает данные

Tags: jquery, json, javascript, kendo

Уже несколько дней бьюсь. Чую, что проблема в какой-то мелочи, но найти не могу.

```
(elem.find('table')).each(function(){
   var params={
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
     refresh: true,
    },
    scrollable: {
     virtual: true
    },
    navigatable: true,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
     transport:{
      create: {
       url: '/entities/'+$(this).attr('data-entity')+'/create.php',
       type: 'POST'
      },
      read: 'entities/'+$(this).attr('data-entity')+'/read.php',
      update: {
       url: '/entities/'+$(this).attr('data-entity')+'/update.php',
       type: 'POST'
      },
      destroy: {
       url: '/entities/'+$(this).attr('data-entity')+'/destroy.php',
       type: 'POST'
      }
     },
     batch: true,
     schema: {
      dataType: "jsonp",
      model: {
       id: "idListener",
       fields: {
        Surname: {  },
        Name: {  },
        Patronymic: {  },
        Phone: {  },
        Email: {  }
       }
      }
     }
    }),
    editable: {
     create: true,
     read: true,
     update: true,
     destroy: true
    },
    toolbar: ['create','save','cancel'],
    columns: [
     { field: "idListener", title: "№ п/п" },
     { field: "Surname", title: "Фамилия" },
     { field: "Name", title: "Имя" },
     { field: "Patronymic", title: "Отчество" },
     { field: "Phone", title: "Телефонный номер" },
     { field: "Email", title: "E-mail" }
    ]
   };
   console.log(params);
   $(this).kendoGrid(params);
  });
```

Фрагмент JSON:

```
callback([{"idListener":"50","Surname":"test","Name":"test","Patronymic":"test","Phone":"","Email":""},
...
])
```

Счётчик элементов, кстати, бредятину выдаёт, то 260, то вообще нечто больше 2000. Шапка таблицы отображается нормально, но вместо данных один пустой ряд, причём мизерной высоты. Запрашиваются и доходят данные точно, проверял инспектором. Пробовал чистый JSON вместо JSONP - результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. Проблема была в том, что JSON отдавался с экранированными UNICODE-символами. Добавил константу JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - всё заработало.